# Does our subconscious retain more than our conscious mind does?

Tags: memory

Such as If you read a book, yet can't recite/directly recall most of it. Is what you read stored in your subconscious or do you forget it right after you read it, or did you not retain it in the first place.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. We work differently to many SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read about conscious vs "subconscious" memories, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Are all conscious experiences stored as memories?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/11060/7001) or one of the similar questions linked in the comments, such as [Does a person's brain still contain a record of daily events?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/3647/7001) or [Are partially forgotten memories still in your brain?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/6402/7001)